# Python XLSXwriter error. Workbook not closing correctly

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I am trying to generate a excel worksheet from a list using the module xlsxwriter, but I keep getting an error that the workbook won't close. Here is the error message, and code. The list is generating data correctly.

Code:

```
    import csv  
import xlsxwriter
f = open('alerts2.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
li1 = []
header = next(csv_f)
for row in csv_f:

    # li1.append(row[5])
    # li1.append(row[0]) 
    severity = int(row[0]) #Has The the integer value from 10 - 40
    if severity != 40:
        continue
    Status = str(row[1])
    PolicyName = str(row[2])
    PolicyBlockName = str(row[3])
    PolicyRuleName = str(row[4])
    Summary = str(row[5])
    li1.append(severity)
    li1.append(Summary) # string variables
print li1
f.close()
print len(li1)
#creating a workbook and a worksheet
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('results_stuff.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

#initializing variables called row and columns for inputting
row = 0
col = 0

#forloop iteration over the data and writing it in row by row
for severity_level, summary_description in (li1):
    worksheet.write(row, col,    severity_level)
    worksheet.write(row, col +1, summary_description)
    row += 1
workbook.close()
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse.py", line 33, in <module>
    for severity_level, summary_description in (li1):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
Exception Exception: Exception('Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close() may be required for workbook.',) in <bound method Workbook.__del__ of <xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook object at 0x1054fefd0>> ignored
```

Comment: li1 is a list. You're not iterating over pairs of the items in: you're trying to convert a single integer into multiple items.

You need to change your append call to `append((Severity, Summary))` so you can iterate as so (over tuples of 2 items).